# Программа для подсчёта времени начала и конца работы

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Мой код.

```
a = [0, 5, 6, 5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 7]
b = [[0], [0], [0], [1], [2], [2], [3, 4], [5], [6, 7]]
z = 0
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    e = a[max(b[i])]
    t = a[i] + a[max(b[i])]
    if t > z:
       z = t
    if len(b[i]) > 1:
        c = a[i] + z

print('№ работы:', i, 'Время начала работы:', e, 'Время окончания:', t)
```

Но почему-то кода дело доходит до двойных значений во втором массиве код работает не правильно.
Не получается написать такой код который в трёх последних значениях использует максимальное значения времени окончания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так...
*(если не экономить буквы и называть переменные осмысленными именами, то сразу становится понятнее)*

```
job_time      = [ 0,   5,   6,   5,   7,   2,   3,      5,   7    ]
jobs_required = [[0], [0], [0], [1], [2], [2], [3, 4], [5], [6, 7]]
end_time      = [ 0 ]
for i in range(1, len(job_time)):
    start_time = max(end_time[job] for job in jobs_required[i])
    end_time.append(start_time + job_time[i])
    print('№ работы:', i, 'Время начала работы:', start_time, 'Время окончания:', end_time[i])
```

Если не понятно что делает строка `start_time = max(end_time[job] for job in jobs_required[i])`, то её эквивалентом будет этот кусок кода:

```
    max_end_time = 0
    for job in jobs_required[i]:
        if end_time[job] > max_end_time:
            max_end_time = end_time[job]
    start_time = max_end_time
```

Или такой код *(который является более приближенным к тому, что делается в той строке)*, если использовать временный список для поиска максимума в нём:

```
    times = []
    for job in jobs_required[i]:
        times.append(end_time[job])
    start_time = max(times)
```

Ну, а *(если вдруг не изучали ещё)* строка вида `что_то.append(что_то_другое)` просто добавляет элемент `что_то_другое` в конец списка `что_то`.

---

Ещё как вариант, можно написать рекурсивную функцию, которая сразу будет выдавать время окончания i-той работы. Если нужно подсчитать только время конкретной работы, то можно через неё. Если нужны все времена, то через неё будет не оптимально.

```
def get_end_time(i):
    return max(get_end_time(job) + job_time[i] for job in jobs_required[i]) if jobs_required[i][0] else job_time[i]

for i in range(1, len(job_time)):
    end_time = get_end_time(i)
    print('№ работы:', i, 'Время начала работы:', end_time - job_time[i], 'Время окончания:', end_time)
```

---

Результат:

```
№ работы: 1 Время начала работы: 0 Время окончания: 5
№ работы: 2 Время начала работы: 0 Время окончания: 6
№ работы: 3 Время начала работы: 5 Время окончания: 10
№ работы: 4 Время начала работы: 6 Время окончания: 13
№ работы: 5 Время начала работы: 6 Время окончания: 8
№ работы: 6 Время начала работы: 13 Время окончания: 16
№ работы: 7 Время начала работы: 8 Время окончания: 13
№ работы: 8 Время начала работы: 16 Время окончания: 23
```

Comment: Ой спасибочки большое, так не умею. Но я пользовался знаниями лишь теми которыми владею, можно сказать как месяц прошёл самостоятельного обучения.

Comment: Ну так в первом варианте ничего сложного. Вам строчку где `max(..)` расписать в классическом варианте?

Comment: @НиколайМирных В общем, расписал в ответе алгоритм как можно более простым кодом.